# Why I obtain a double click event instead of a single one in an UWP listbox?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a list box with some elements. in my Page.XAML page I have something like:

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="SelectedIndexChanged" x:Name="myList" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="350" Height="900" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" RequestedTheme="Default" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" Background="Transparent">
```

I created the SelectedIndexChanged event to check when I click on one element of the listbox:

Page.XAML.cs

```
 private async void SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int itemIndex = myList.SelectedIndex;

        var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("What do you want to do?", "Alert!");
        messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Do It", null));
        messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Don't do it", null));
        messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Cancel", null));
        var cmdClick = await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine(itemIndex);
        if (cmdClick.Label == "Do It")
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Do It");
            myList.Items.RemoveAt(itemIndex);
            return;
        }
        if (cmdClick.Label == "Don't do it")
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("No defect");
            myList.Items.RemoveAt(itemIndex);
            return;
        }
        if (cmdClick.Label == "Cancel")
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Cancel");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Everything seems to be correct but when I click on one button of the window dialog (after one element of the list box is selected), the window dialog appears again for a total of two times instead of just return to the main window.

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: You select one item, first SelectedIndexChanged is fired.,Then in the first 2 `if`s you remove current selected item from the list, so the selected index change again and a second event is fired

Comment: so, how do you suggest to manage this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [Gian Paolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3276027/gian-paolo) in the comment the 2nd event is fired since you are removing the selected item from the list .

> When you remove the currently selected item, the `SelectedIndex` goes
>   to the default value, which is **-1** . Thus if the user had selected an
>   item at index **X** , after the item removal it changes to **-1**, hence it
>   triggers the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

*-1 `SelectedIndex` means that there is currently no selected item in the list .*

---

Thus easiest way to resolve this issue is to just add a check to see if the selected index is -1 or not .

```
 private async void SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int itemIndex = myList.SelectedIndex;
        //checking if the selected index is -1 (or no item is actually selected)
        if (itemIndex != -1)
        {
            var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("What do you want to do?", "Alert!");
            messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Do It", null));
            messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Don't do it", null));
            messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Cancel", null));
            var cmdClick = await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine(itemIndex);
            if (cmdClick.Label == "Do It")
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Do It");
                myList.Items.RemoveAt(itemIndex);
                return;
            }
            if (cmdClick.Label == "Don't do it")
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("No defect");
                myList.Items.RemoveAt(itemIndex);
                return;
            }
            if (cmdClick.Label == "Cancel")
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Cancel");
                return;
            }
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps !